# How to attach a csv file to php email (code running from the magento root)

Tags: php, magento, csv, smtp, sendmail

I am having following code in the magento root directory to send email.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app("default");

$body = "Hi there, here is some body content";
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('John');
$mail->setToEmail('ab@example.net');
$mail->setBody($body);
$mail->setSubject('The Subject');
$mail->setFromEmail('yourstore@url.com');
$mail->setFromName("Your Name");
$mail->setType('text');// You can use 'html' or 'text'

try {
    $mail->send();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');

}

?>
```

How can I attach multiple csv files with this email.(At least 3 or 4).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use zend and this code is tested

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
umask( 0 );
Mage :: app( "default" );
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setType(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_RELATED);
$mail->setBodyHtml($html_body);
$mail->setFrom('support@example.com', 'Example');
$mail->addTo('dev.amitbera@gmail.com', 'Amit');
$mail->setSubject('Sending email using Zend Framework');
$dir = Mage::getBaseDir();
$path = $dir.DS.'var'.DS.'docs'.DS.'test.csv';
$file = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($path));
$file ->type        = 'text/csv';
$file ->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
$file ->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$file ->filename    = 'test.csv';
$mail->send();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think they internally use PHPMailer, so that's really easy:

```
$mail->addAttachment('csv/test.csv');
```

Comment: Can I add multiple attachements?

Comment: Yes, just call the function again.

Comment: I am getting following errror 
 Uncaught exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Core_Model_Email::addAttachment(Array
(
    [0] =&gt; csv/output.csv
)

Comment: Ok, then they don't support that function. Do you mind to include PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)? It supports that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dir = Mage::getBaseDir();
$file_name = $dir.DS.'var'.DS.'docs'.DS.'test.csv'; //file path
if(file_exists($file_name))
{
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($file_name);
    $fileName = 'test.csv';
    $mail->addAttachment($fileContents, $fileName);
}
```

Comment: I am getting following
Fatal error Uncaught exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Core_Model_Email::addAttachment

Comment: wait i will reply with in  1hr

Comment: Magento  'core/email' model can not send attachment. So,you should used core/email_template model.that can send attachment... f you want to send this model then it will provide codes

Comment: Please check my last answer

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses the zend_mail frame work. You can call the getMail function to access this framework to add an attachement.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.attachments.html

Example :

```
$transactionalEmail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')>setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>1));

$transactionalEmail->getMail()->createAttachment($fileContents,'text/csv')->filename =$filename;

$transactionalEmail->sendTransactional($templateID, $sender, $email, "Admin", $vars);
```

Comment: can you please explain the use of variables used in last line of your answer? And what is $fileContents